# CakePHP LocaleSelectorMiddleware Not Working

Tags: php, xampp, cakephp-3.7

I just can't get the below code to be invoked in CakePHP 3.7. I have changed the needed language on my browser to French, but it does not work, and I only get the English version. Yes, I do have all the proper .po files in place.

```
public function middleware($middlewareQueue)

{
    $middlewareQueue

        // Add middleware and set the valid locales
        ->add(new LocaleSelectorMiddleware(['fr_FR']));

    return $middlewareQueue;
}
```

Comment: _"I just can't get the below code to be invoked..."_ Does this mean you're sure it's actually never being called? If so, it seems like you should go back and review your app's configuration for reasons this function would be getting skipped. Are there any warnings in the logs that might indicate a problem?

Comment: Thank you @kungphu - I've been going over the codes and can't seem to see why it wouldn't work. If I add I18n::setLocale('fr_FR') in my Controller file, it works flawlessly, I just can't get it to work automatically based on the browser locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation. All I can add is that the [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#automatically-choosing-the-locale-based-on-request-data) mentions a DispatcherFactory. However, that approach seems to be deprecated.

I haven't yet found if and by what DispatcherFactory needs to be replaced, but it could be that without it or its replacement, adding the middleware is just not enough.

[Doc for DispatcherFactory](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html) states that as of 3.3.0, middleware should be used. But I've not yet been able to get it to work.

UPDATE: I checked my request headers, and Chrome set Accept-Language to values like 'en' and 'fr' among others. So I include what I want in my LocaleSelectorMiddleware in the correct format, and that does the trick.

I replaced 'en_US' with 'en' for instance, and 'fr_BE' with 'fr'.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.